# Requesting REST-GET gives me 403 but works fine in DHC

Tags: javascript, 8

I am stuck for hours now with a JSON REST problem:

I have a simple REST endpoint in my Drupal 8 App. If I call it with the DHC Chromium REST Extension like GET http://proreos/api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json, I get

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2016:15:03:54 +0200] "GET /api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 477 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/51.0.2704.79 Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36"
```

That's wonderful. Also Drupal does all the requested processing.
But if I call it from curl like

`curl 'http://proreos/api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json'`

I get the bad 403 response:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2016:15:10:27 +0200] "GET /api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json HTTP/1.1" 403 409 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

Well actually, I want to call it from a JS plugin like:

```
function checkLawyer() {
  var server = drupalSettings.bootasde.proreos_server;
  var id = drupalSettings.bootasde.asdeid;
  var jUrl = server+'api/v1/checklawyer/'+id+'?_format=json';
  console.log('Q: '+jUrl);
  jQuery.getJSON(jUrl);
}
```

It works fine, but unfortunately, it also gives me a 403 without any further Drupal backend processing:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2016:15:06:03 +0200] "GET /api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json HTTP/1.1" 403 464 "http://proreos/asde/anwalt/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
```

Console says:

```
15:17:22.973 "Q: http://proreos/api/v1/checklawyer/1?_format=json"
XHR HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Any idea would be great! Thanks.

Comment: It's a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) failure (the clue is the `XHR` part of your response)  - either the site hosting the JS needs to be on the domain `proreos`, or you need a cross origin access header on the Drupal site

Comment: It's even more crazy: If I paste the URI into chromium it works, in firefox it does not work - while the request headers are totally ident (except from the UA).

Comment: Not crazy at all - a normal HTTP request will work, an XHR won't...

Comment: Oh, not sure about the FF thing. That's why I stopped using it. Chrome always just works like it should

Comment: But there is no CrossOrigin, everything is localhost with proreos alias.

Comment: So just to confirm, `drupalSettings.bootasde.proreos_server` contains `http://proreos/` and nothing else?

Comment: Yes. Think it's a pure FF problem. In Chromium the complete end2end processing is totally fine.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. FF does things like this; in their defence, they're usually complying with some part of a spec that no one else is. But it produces inconsistent behaviour and confuses people. Not sure whether it should be judged as right or wrong to be honest

Comment: I am fairly certain this is not a CORS issue because the response would be valid, but you would not be able to access the content (or content body is 0 bytes in firefox). This is an authentication issue. Ninja edit: As I was thinking about it, @Rainer Feike confirmed my suspicions in his answer.

Comment: @mradcliffe Yeah you're right, I obviously only read half the question. Just saw the JS and response containing `XHR`, jumped to a conclusion

Answer (score 1):

Doomed, I am so stupid. Chrome had the admin cookie, FF had a simple user cookie. I forgot to permit the GET on the new endpoint in the user permissions!!!

So stupid. @Clive: Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for that waste of time.